# Using default arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to make constructor with default arguments. 
Something like this

```
Object(int size = 1) {
//SMTH
}
```

I am trying to do like this in visual studio, but error apears. 
Is it possible to create constructor with default arguments or it only remains to use overloading ?

**EDIT**

It is possible, sorry for posting this question, I am newbie in c++. The problem was that I was declaring default argument in source file (cpp) , I have changed my class like this and it works great.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass (int i = 0, std::string s = "");  // constructor declared

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string z;
};

MyClass :: MyClass(int i, std::string s)     // constructor defined
{
    x = 100;
    y = i;
    z = s;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Maybe it might help us solve the issue.

Comment: What is the error? Have you searched about it?

Comment: I tried `class Foo 
{
        public:
                Foo(int a = 5)
                {   
                }   
};`

which definitely worked, so it would be more useful if we knew what the error was.

Comment: Is this constructor inside the class definition?

Comment: Really useless question, 'an error appears', what error?

Comment: Sorry , I have forgotten to paste error .  'pointerArray::pointerArray' : cannot declare default arguments for member functions of a managed type or generic functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have constructors with default arguments.

Two caveats regarding your particular example:

- Make sure you don't also have a no-args constructor as this would lead to ambiguity.
- You might want to make this constructor `explicit` so that it's not used for implicit conversion from `int` to `Object`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the default constructor here